# Runtime error 91: Object Variable or With block variable not set - Need suggestion

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I am working on a report which consists of ActiveX plugins and the data is supposed to filter based on change in the selection. All works well, but I am getting the "RUNTIME ERROR 91" every time I open the file with different filename.

I need to share these password-protected files to more than 10 clients at once and don't want them to get these errors.

My code:

```
Sub advancedfilter_protect()

    'Disable Screen Updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim actvsht As Worksheet
    
    Set actvsht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        For Each actvsht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        actvsht.Activate
        actvsht.Unprotect "Password"
        Next
    
            Call advancedfilter_data
    
        For Each actvsht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            actvsht.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `Set actvsht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`.

Comment: You may also want to read [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Its suggestions also apply to avoiding using `Activate` and `ActiveSheet` and so on.

Comment: And that made it look so easy. Code works well now. Thanks